# jquery datepicker is not work because WYSIWYG

Tags: jquery, datepicker, wysiwyg

i have a datepicker, it is working well before, But after i add a richtext editor WYSIWYG datepicker is npt working.

This is my code :

```
<!-- library for date picker-->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
     <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <!--end of jquery datepicker--> 
     <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/wysiwyg.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/wysiwyg-settings.js"></script> 
     <script type="text/javascript">
     $.noConflict();
                $(document).ready(function() {
                  $('#tglgabung').daterangepicker({
                   singleDatePicker: true,
                    calender_style: "picker_4"

                  }, function(start, end, label) {
                    console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
                  });
                });
              </script>




        <script type="text/javascript">
                WYSIWYG.attach('textarea3', full); // small setup

            </script>
```

pls help me, i have tried using jquery noconflict, but nothing happened.
pls check, if my code is wrong ?

thank you .

Comment: Is there any error showing in your console?

Comment: can you replicate this issue in `jsfiddle`?